# VSCode takes a lot of time to Load Java Projects on creating

Tags: java, spring-boot

VScode takes a really long time to load a Java project on creating it for the first time also can I change files(start writing my code in the files during this Opening process)

I have just started learning Java Full Stack. I am using VSCode and I dont think I am going to switch IDE. So, the problem I face is everytime I create a new Java project it says Opening Java projects check details and it keeps loading for a very long time. Can I fix this anyway or atleast can I check how much time is it going to take to open this java project and also can I change the files and start learning while this opening process is going on???

Answer (score 0):

Language Support for Java v1.15.0  = Seems broken

Change the version doing the downgrade to the

Language Support for Java to v1.14.0.